# Questions about the Floris Mod

Tags: mods, mount-and-blade-warband

I just started playing the game (single player), and really getting into it. But I'm not sure whether the game is worth playing through once first as is or by applying for example `Floris Mod Packs` and playing with it.

It seems to be a collection of 72 mods or something. Would I be losing play value of the original? or is it all uphill improvement. And will multi-player still work?

I also read that it is not compatible with my current save, hence why Id rather find out now than later.

Has anyone had any experience with Floris mod? Is it easily reverted if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big mods like the Floris Pack are independent from the Native game in Mount and Blade. The mod is installed in it's own folder, and you must choose it before launching the game. Therefore, reverting back to Native is just a matter of sectioning Native over the mod.

Saves are also mod specific, so your save with the mod will mot be mixed with Native saves, your previous save remains unaffected.

The Floris pack in itself aims at adding new functionality to the Native game while still conserving the feeling of the original. It is not compatible with the multiplayer, but you can just go back to native for it.

Comment: Ah right. That sounds ideal. Do you recommend the Floris experience over the native experience (Single player campaign)?

Comment: I would strongly recommend Floris. There is a reason that it exists... Native has annoying quirks and oddities. Don't worry too much about it, Floris was specifically designed to mimic the Native style.
Multiplayer won't be changed, you will just choose whichever mod/native you need depending on the server.

Comment: @Lawton and Jupotter. Thanks both for the help. :) I'll restart my SP game on Floris tonight.